# Get documents with tags in list, ordered by total number of matches

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Given the following MongoDB collection of documents :

```
{
 title : 'shirt one'
 tags : [
  'shirt',
  'cotton',
  't-shirt',
  'black'
 ]
},
{
 title : 'shirt two'
 tags : [
  'shirt',
  'white',
  'button down collar'
 ]
},
{
 title : 'shirt three'
 tags : [
  'shirt',
  'cotton',
  'red'
 ]
},
...
```

How do you retrieve a list of items matching a list of tags, ordered by the total number of matched tags?  For example, given this list of tags as input:

```
['shirt', 'cotton', 'black']
```

I'd want to retrieve the items ranked in desc order by total number of matching tags:

```
item          total matches
--------      --------------
Shirt One     3 (matched shirt + cotton + black)
Shirt Three   2 (matched shirt + cotton)
Shirt Two     1 (matched shirt)
```

In a relational schema, tags would be a separate table, and you could join against that table, count the matches, and order by the count.

But, in Mongo... ?

Seems this approach could work,

- break the input tags into multiple "IN" statements
- query for items by "OR"'ing together the tag inputs

  - i.e. where ( 'shirt' IN items.tags ) OR ( 'cotton' IN items.tags )
  - this would return, for example, three instances of "Shirt One", 2 instances of "Shirt Three", etc
- map/reduce that output

  - map: emit(this._id, {...});
  - reduce: count total occurrences of _id
  - finalize: sort by counted total

But I'm not clear on how to implement this as a Mongo query, or if this is even the most efficient approach.

Comment: No M/R is simple in production code since the current implementation lacks proper parallelism. In fact a good case can be made for avoiding m/r altogether in high throughput situations.

Answer (score 9):

As i answered in [In MongoDB search in an array and sort by number of matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405837/in-mongodb-search-in-an-array-and-sort-by-number-of-matches/12409227#12409227)

It's possible using Aggregation Framework.

**Assumptions**

- `tags` attribute is a set (no repeated elements)

**Query**

This approach forces you to unwind the results and reevaluate the match predicate with unwinded results, so its really inefficient.

```
db.test_col.aggregate(
    {$match: {tags: {$in: ["shirt","cotton","black"]}}}, 
    {$unwind: "$tags"}, 
    {$match: {tags: {$in: ["shirt","cotton","black"]}}},
    {$group: {
        _id:{"_id":1}, 
        matches:{$sum:1}
    }}, 
    {$sort:{matches:-1}}
);
```

**Expected Results**

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5051f1786a64bd2c54918b26")
            },
            "matches" : 3
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5051f1726a64bd2c54918b24")
            },
            "matches" : 2
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5051f1756a64bd2c54918b25")
            },
            "matches" : 1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Samuel Answer is correct. I just dispute the additional information that it's inefficient. In order to match someone will have to unwind the tags anyway performing this task in the aggregation pipeline might be the fastest approach for adhoc queries

Comment: This answer worked great for me however I did have to make a small change in the `$group` object to make this work in Mongo 3.0. and use this for the ID `_id:{"_id":"$_id"}`

Comment: Yes, indeed. The grouping _id format has changed in version 3.0, and now you can use that format or the nested one but with $ symbol also.

Answer (score 5):

Right now, it isnt possible to do unless you use MapReduce.  The only problem with MapReduce is that it is slow (compared to a normal query).

The aggregation framework is slated for 2.2 (so should be available in 2.1 dev release) and should make this sort of thing much easier to do without MapReduce.

Personally, I do not think using M/R is an efficient way to do it.  I would rather query for all the documents and do those calculations on the application side.  It is easier and cheaper to scale your app servers than it is to scale your database servers so let the app servers do the number crunching.  Of those, this approach may not work for you given your data access patterns and requirements.

An even simpler approach may be to just include a `count` property in each of your tag objects and whenever you `$push` a new tag to the array, you also `$inc` the `count` property.  This is a common pattern in the MongoDB world, at least until the aggregation framework.

Comment: Including a count property when $push'ing a new tag to the array would not help given this problem, as wount could simply indicate total tags (not the total tags matching the input).

Answer (score 1):

I'll second @Bryan in saying that MapReduce is the only possible way at the moment (and it's far from perfect). But, in case you desperately need it, here you go :-)

```
    var m = function() {
        var searchTerms = ['shirt', 'cotton', 'black'];
        var me = this;
        this.tags.forEach(function(t) {
            searchTerms.forEach(function(st) {
                if(t == st) {
                    emit(me._id, {matches : 1});
                }
            })
        })
    };

    var r = function(k, vals) {
        var result = {matches : 0};
        vals.forEach(function(v) {
            result.matches += v.matches;
        })
        return result;
    };

    db.shirts.mapReduce(m, r, {out: 'found01'});

    db.found01.find();
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good start.  But, rather than run the map/reduce on *all* items in the collection, wouldn't it be faster to do do an initial find by OR'ing together input tags?  This would reduce the size of the set processed in m(), and r() could simply return vals.length as the total matches?