# Mongo find and rank result

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo collection that has docs similar to the schema below. And I have a ui from which a user could filter on the attributes (using logical or). Since its using OR I want the results to be ordered such that I first get the ones that match the most filters. For example: if i filter on author "auth1" and "tag1" I get back both records but the second record is on top. In this example I just have 2 attr to filter on, but there are about 20.

Do you have any suggestions of the best way of tackling this? I was thinking of writing a map-reduce query to compute the "match rank".

```
{name: "bookName", tags:["tag1"], authors: [] }
{name: "bookName2", tags:["tag1", "tag2"], authors: ["auth1", "auth2"] }
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your proble, You wants sort the result By authors.length and tags.length.

The problem, in MongoDB (I test on 2.6) with the `sort()`, it is impossible to sort by two parallels arrays. You can sort by album.length or tags.length but not both.

```
// sort By max to min authors
db.getCollection('rank').find({}).sort({ authors : -1 });
// sort by max to min tags
db.getCollection('rank').find({}).sort({ tags : -1 });
```

If you watn sort your result by both of them, you should use the Aggregation Framework. You have a great explanation here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9040269/1506914

Comment: I wasnt trying to sort on the length of the arrays. I need to sort such that when I search for tag1 tag2 and auth1, i get back both of my records but bookname2 is on top as it matched on all 3 of the filters. Bookname1 would be at the bottom as it matched just tag1. Hope this makes more sense

Answer (score -1):

It is possible using Aggregation Framework. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405837/in-mongodb-search-in-an-array-and-sort-by-number-of-matches), it's similar to yours.