# Query search element array in mongo

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

[MONGO] I have a collection of places which is like this :

```
[
    { item: "journal",tags: ["blank", "red","blue","yellow"]},
    { item: "notebook",tags: ["red", "pink","green"]},
    { item: "paper", tags: ["red", "blank", "plain","black"]},
    { item: "planner",tags: ["blank", "blue","gray"]},
    { item: "postcard",tags: ["blue"] }
]
```

I want search for tags with 1 array search:["red", "blank","black"], how to get items, which the tags contains at least 1 element on aray search. and sorting .

expect result:

```
[
    { item: "paper",tags: ["red", "blank", "plain","black"]},
    { item: "journal",tags: ["blank", "red","blue","yellow"]},
    { item: "notebook",tags: ["red", "pink","green"]},
    { item: "planner", tags: ["blank", "blue","gray"]},
]
```

Comment: Did you meant JavaScript? as you tagged mongoose...

Comment: i wana search on mongo.

Comment: then please make your question clear and use proper tags, as it's confusing right now what exactly you want

Comment: sory .I edited it. can you help me?

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want a search query that returns all items that match *any* ot these tags, i.e. any that are assigned to "red", "blank", *or* "black"?

Comment: yes, i do. and sort result

Comment: My English level is poor. ((

Comment: You can use the `$or`operator. see answer below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44182548/mongo-sort-by-count-of-matches-in-array
](Mongo Sort by Count of Matches in Array)

Comment: Afridi, thank y. This is the thing that is needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find all documents in a collection `myitems`, you can use the [`$or` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/), an [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) and the [sort function](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/).

Here's the query how to find for any element that either has the tag "red", "blank" or "black":

```
db.myitems.aggregate([
  {$project : 
    {tags: 1, item: 1, tag_count: {$size: "$tags" } }
  }, 
  {$match: 
    {$or: [{tags: "red"}, {tags: "blank"}, {tags: "black"}]} 
  }, 
  {$sort: {"tag_count": -1} } 
]);
```

This will return something like this:

```
{ "item" : "journal", "tags" : [ "blank", "red", "blue", "yellow" ], "tag_count" : 4 }
{ "item" : "paper", "tags" : [ "red", "blank", "plain", "black" ], "tag_count" : 4 }
{ "item" : "notebook", "tags" : [ "red", "pink", "green" ], "tag_count" : 3 }
{ "item" : "planner", "tags" : [ "blank", "blue", "gray" ], "tag_count" : 3 }
```

**Explanation**:

This uses the [Aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) in MongoDB, makes a [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) of the given database in order to get the "tags" size, filters using the [match projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match) and an [`$or` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) over the tags and finally sorts the array over the "tags" size.

Hope this helps.

Comment: but i want to sort items by the matching number of element

Comment: [
    { item: "paper",tags: ["red", "blank", "plain","black"]},// mactch 3 "red","blank","black"
    { item: "journal",tags: ["blank", "red","blue","yellow"]},//macth 2 "blank", "red"
    { item: "notebook",tags: ["red", "pink","green"]},// match 1 "red"
    { item: "planner", tags: ["blank", "blue","gray"]}, // match 1 "blank"
]
sort decrease

Comment: updated it once more: added projection (`$project`, `$match`, `$sort`).