# How to weight documents to create sort criteria?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to aggregate a collection in which there are documents that look like this:

```
[
  {  
    "title" : 1984,
    "tags" : ['dystopia', apocalypse', 'future',....]
  },
  ....
]
```

And I have a criteria array of keywords, for instance:

```
var keywords = ['future', 'google', 'cat',....]
```

What I would like to achieve is to aggregate the collection in order to $group it according to a "convenience" criteria in order to sort the document by the one that contains the more of the keywords in its tags field.

This means, if one document contains in its tags: 'future', 'google', 'cat' it will be sorted before another one that has 'future', 'cat', 'apple'.

So far, I have tried something like this:

```
db.books.aggregate(
   { $group : { _id : {title:"$title"} , convenience: { $sum: { $cond: [ {tags: {$in: keywords}}, 1, 0 ] } } } },
            { $sort : {'convenience': -1}})
```

But the `$in` operator is not a boolean so it does not work. I've looked around and didn't find any operator that could help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you need a logical operator in order to evaluate [$cond](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/). It's a bit terse, but here is an implementation using [$or](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/or/#exp._S_or) :

```
db.books.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$tags" },
    {$group: {
        _id: "$title",
        weight: {
            $sum: {$cond: [
               // Test *equality* of the `tags` value against any of the list 
               {$or: [
                   {$eq: ["$tags", "future"]},
                   {$eq: ["$tags", "google"]},
                   {$eq: ["$tags", "cat"]},
               ]},
            1, 0 ]}
        }
    }}
])
```

I'll leave the rest of the implementation up to you, but this should show the basic construction to the point of the matching you want to do.

### Addition

From your comments there also seem to be a programming issue you are struggling with, related to how you perform an aggregation like this where you have an **Array** of items to query in the form you gave above:

```
var keywords = ['future', 'google', 'cat',....]
```

Since this structure cannot be directly employed in the pipeline condition, what you need to do is *transform* it into what you need. Each language has it's own approach, but in a JavaScript version:

```
var keywords = ['future', 'google', 'cat'];
var orCondition = [];

keywords.forEach(function(value) {
    var doc = {$eq: [ "$tags", value ]};
    orCondition.push(doc);
});
```

And then just define the aggregation query with the `orCondition` variable in place:

```
db.books.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$tags" },
    {$group: {
        _id: "$title",
        weight: {
            $sum: {$cond: [
               {$or: orCondition }
            1, 0 ]}
        }
    }}
])
```

Or for that matter, any of the parts you need to construct. This is generally how it is done in the real world, where we  would almost never hard-code a data structure like this.

Comment: Thanks Neil. It sort of worked. Actually, my problem is that the array keywords come from an input field, then the length and content is not defined nor steady. I'd need a solution in which the $unwind works both sides...

Comment: @user2988332 I saw in your question that you were defining a variable and just passing it in to the aggregate stage. In the real world we would almost never hard-code such a structure as shown, but generate it from the data we have. That means you *create* the structure in the $or conditions dynamically with each query.

Comment: @user2988332 I think the edit with additional information might clear up what you appear to be looking for.

Comment: It worked nicely. I use your answer mixed with this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/12409666/2988332

Now, I think that according with what you said, my reasoning is not going in the direction of the real world. What I'm actually trying to accomplish is to sort a list of books documented on the DB according to an array of keywords that the user enters. The convenience is calculated according to the convenience of the tags. Is there a better way?

Comment: @user2988332 HeHe! That is probably another question. So feel free to ask of the community in that context.