# Sort query by content (not by order)

Tags: mongodb, sorting, meteor

I am trying to sort my mongodb query according to the occurence of a string in one of its fields (an array). So given this example dataset:

```
id | hits | categories
------------------------------
1  | 18   | ['sports']
2  | 12   | ['sports', 'news']
3  | 22   | []
4  | 20   | ['news']
```

I would like to make a query like this one (`$includes` is obviously a made-up keyword):

```
Records.find({}, {sort: {$includes: {categories: 'news'}, hits: -1});
```

Which would give me the resulting output:

```
id | hits | categories
------------------------------
4  | 20   | ['news']
2  | 12   | ['sports', 'news']
3  | 22   | []
1  | 18   | ['sports']
```

Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: You can do this by adding weights to the words in the aggregation framework by using conditions ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861150/weightning-documents-to-create-sort-criteria-in-mongodb like that ) but I would strongly advise against it

Comment: @Sammaye Why would you advise against it?

Comment: I don't even think aggregate can be used in a meteor publication... so I don't know if it is very worth the investigation

Comment: @Philipp Supeeeer slow way of doing it. You will be sorting without an index, but there is no better