# Sort users by distance from current user reactively in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, geolocation, distance

I have [already been](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24757433/sort-query-by-content-not-by-order) facing [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24753114/securing-access-to-collection-from-the-clients-side) in meteor when dealing with reactive sorting of a publication according to various data. Every time, I never found a real answer to what I was trying to achieve and I ended up giving up and just deciding "not to build my app that way", which always makes me really sad.

Now maybe I can phrase this problem simply enough that it could get a constructive and very interesting answer. I think it sounds like it *should* be possible to be done in a Meteor app, so here it is:

I store the locations of my users in "lat" and "lon" variables in my Accounts.users collection. I want the current user to get a list of, say, the 10 closest users to him or her. How would I do this, considering the [seemingly complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/365853/1439597) set of operations needed to get that distance from latitude and longitude?

As far as I know, it is pretty much impossible to insert such an equation in a MongoDB query condition. So how do other people achieve this feat?

I would appreciate any insight on this problem, as theoretical as it may be.

Comment: If you use mysql, it can support spatial features and supports various GIS functions.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436396/mysql-spatial-distance-using-point-not-working for an example where someone is computing distance.

Comment: Thank you ! Very interesting, will look into it :) Although, Meteor doesn't allow any other DBMS than MongoDB. :/ I hear there is a way to sort of make it work with MySQL, but I'm not on a hurry to start hacking around.

Comment: Doesn't the [$near](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) operator do what you want?

Comment: Wow, mongodb has an operator for that?! Thank you, will try this out!

Comment: Don't forget right data type and index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at my working example [localgeo](http://localgeo.meteor.com/) and sources on [github](https://github.com/n0ne/localgeo)

You can find like this:

```
   var nearMarkers = allMarkers.find({
      location: {
        $near: {
          $geometry: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: location
          },
          $maxDistance: radius
        }
      }
    });
```

Location is this [type](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/) of MongoDB. And remember: in MongoDB Lng - first, Lat - second, I don't know why. I do it on client side, but you can make publication in the same way, depend on radius.

Comment: How does the `$near` sorting figure into other sorting modifiers? For instance, if I use `sort` as an option in the `find` method on the server, will it sort first by distance, then by other factors, or the opposite?

Comment: I don't have the answer, but in MongoDB docs I found this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/#sort-operation

Comment: Yeah, I already looked at that.  It doesn't seem to have any indication of priority.